# Calling W3C RSS Validator API returns Http 403 in .NET

Tags: .net, rss, http-status-code-403, w3c-validation

I am trying to implement remote call to W3C RSS Validator service:

http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/soap.html

By the description it looks like I need to form a call something like this:

http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=www.test.com&output=soap12

And it totally works in browser. When I am making .NET call it does return 403: Forbidden. Protocol Exception.

My code:

```
var p = "http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=" + url + "&output=soap12";
            WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(p);            


            WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
```